# How to display Arabic numbers in RDLC reports?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, arabic

I want to display Arabic number in my report.

I tried to set the `Language` property to `ar` but it's not working. also tried a lot of things but none of them are working :(

Any idea how to make it?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean [Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numeral)? These are just the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9. Unless you want to use Arabic font or something? Or maybe you actually mean [Roman numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals)?

Comment: I mean like this `(٠‎ - ١‎ - ٢‎ - ٣‎ - ٤‎ - ٥‎ - ٦‎ - ٧‎ - ٨‎ - ٩‎)`

Comment: the best solution is changing the [Use native digits] to Context from windows region and language.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the NumeralVariant property of the TextBox to "3". You also need an Arabic language installed on your operating system.

Comment: It Worked for me. @SzamDev you should use an Arabic font that write numbers in arabic.   thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this function to set any string that contain english numbers and convert them into arabic or indian numiric charachters in the source of report befor pass that source to report
`

```
public string ArabicNumiric(string englishNo)
        {
            char[] arNumiricsChar = { '٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩' };
           // char[] arNumiricsChar =new char[]{ '٠'‎ , '١', '٢'‎ , '٣'‎, '٤', '٥'‎, '٦'‎, '٧'‎, '٨'‎, '٩' };           
            string araNO = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(englishNo))
            {
                char[] englishNoCharArray = englishNo.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < englishNoCharArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    int noTst;
                    if (int.TryParse(englishNoCharArray[i].ToString(), out noTst))
                    {
                        englishNoCharArray[i] = arNumiricsChar[noTst];
                        araNO += englishNoCharArray[i];
                    }
                    else
                        araNO += englishNoCharArray[i];
                }
            }
            return araNO;
        }
```

`

Comment: Code only answers are not considered as useful. Please provide some contextual information.

Answer (score 0):

the  answer   is   simple    be   creative   make your  report  in  standard  numbers then
replace "1"  with "١‎"      (  copy  and  paste )  this  will  work 
replace "2"  with "٢‎ "

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel > Change keyboards or other input method > Formats > Additional Settings.
Change [Use native digits] combo box value to [Context]